# What is the firebase database rules when we do phone number authentication in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my firebase database rule console I have declare the rules when I do mobile number authentication & the rules are as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

when I run my app the database error occurs that **"Database Error : Permission Denied"**.

so what's the solution of this?

Comment: have u done with this error or Set the firebase rules for your database?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare rules like that, you're saying that the user must be logged in to read or write any and all of the database.  If there is no user logged in, any reads or writes from your app will yield that error.  So, you should check to make sure a user is a logged in before doing anything with the database.

Comment: yes sir in onStart() method of the activity I check the user is logged in or not, but still this continues